# Spring Roo for larger applications

Tags: java, spring, performance, scalability, spring-roo

Spring Roo appears to be a great framework with true order of magnitude productivity improvements. However I am reading that Roo aims mainly at rapid prototyping or smaller applications.

My question is, whether Spring Roo has proved to be suited also for larger, production-ready web applications, subject to important scalability and performance requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Roo is a development tool, it is not a framework.

There has no sense querying about if Spring Roo has been proved for scalability and performance for any production web app because it is not a runtime framework, it is a development tool for development time.

Spring Roo creates web apps based on Spring Framework, Spring MVC, and other frameworks that have been proved to be suited for larger production-ready web applications.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Let me then put the focus on maintainability. Would you say that Spring Roo provides for development-time capabilities, necessary for larger applications, like encapsulation, partitioning, changeability, reuse etc? Can the Roo scripting language and overall generator infrastructure cope well with an increasing code base?

Comment: What do you mean about encapsulation? As I know it is a term related to OOP not related to specific development tool. And what do you mean about partitioning, changeability, reuse, etc. related to devel tool? Roo hasn't an scripting language, it has a set of commands that you can group together in a batch file (.roo file) ... please I would request you read the reference guide and then you ask for more specific topics.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question pragmatically: We are planning a new version of a large web application that is expected to have more than 500 database entities. We expect more than 100 users to simultaneously login. We are considering to use Roo along with GWT. Do you see any problems with it?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of GWT. I would recommend you Roo with Spring MVC. On the other side, in my company we use gvNIX as development tool, a Roo distribution that includes Datatables, jQuery, Bootstrap 3 and more. To learn more visit www.gvnix.org. Here you have a good reference of a project developed with gvNIX: http://www.europapress.es/comunitat-valenciana/noticia-cerca-40-empleados-publicos-solicita-carrera-profesional-primeras-24-horas-20141123115615.html (spanish)